# Removing a folder via ssh in Github Actions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, github-actions

there is an issue for deleting a folder before copying the updated project to a deployment server. I want run this command:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no backend@${{ secrets.SERVER_ADDRESS }} 'rm -R /var/www/dist/laundry-receipt'
```

Authentication and permissions are set up correctly. The logs from github actions show:

```
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
command-line line 0: no argument after keyword "r" 
lost connection
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Has anybody seen something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem was related to the next command.